# How to know what size of bike is suitable for your height and weight?

Tags: bike-fit

There are many parameters when buying a bike, but the important one is the bike size. I want to know how to get the specs for the bike. Any good websites that help you in this regard?

Comment: please use the search box top right, this question has been asked before

Comment: Got it!
http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/bike-size-to-human-size-
conversion-chart